# Dataframe with several list convert in column in spark structured streaming

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following problem, I have a dataframe in **spark structured streaming** that contains two columns with a list of dictionaries. The scheme that I have created for the data structure that I have is the following:

```
        tick_by_tick_schema = StructType([
            StructField('localSymbol', StringType()),
            StructField('tickByTicks', ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('price', StringType()),
                StructField('size', StringType()),
                StructField('specialConditions', StringType()),
            ]))),
            StructField('domBids', ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('price_bid', StringType()),
                StructField('size_bid', StringType()),
                StructField('marketMaker_bid', StringType()),
            ]))),
            StructField('domAsks', ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('price_ask', StringType()),
                StructField('size_ask', StringType()),
                StructField('marketMaker_ask', StringType()),
            ])))
        ])
```

My dataframe is this:

```
+-----------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|localSymbol|tickByTicks       |domBids                                                                                             |domAsks                                                                                          |
+-----------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|BABA       |[{213.73, 134, T}]|[{213.51, 1, ARCA}, {213.51, 1, NSDQ}, {213.5, 12, NSDQ}, {213.06, 1, ARCA}, {213.01, 10, DRCTEDGE}]|[{213.75, 45, ARCA}, {213.95, 1, DRCTEDGE}, {214.0, 1, ARCA}, {214.0, 1, NSDQ}, {214.1, 1, NSDQ}]|
+-----------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now what I would like to get is something like this:

```
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
|localSymbol|price |price_bid|price_ask|
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
|BABA       |213.73|213.51   |213.75   |
|BABA       |213.73|213.51   |213.95   |
|BABA       |213.73|213.5    |214.0    |
|BABA       |213.73|213.06   |214.0    |
|BABA       |213.73|213.01   |214.1    | 
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
```

i tried this:

```
        df = self.tick_by_tick_data_processed\
            .withColumn('price', f.explode(f.col('tickByTicks.price'))) \
            .withColumn('price_ask', f.explode(f.col('domAsks.price_ask'))) \
            .withColumn('price_bid', f.explode(f.col('domBids.price_bid'))).select('localSymbol','price','price_bid','price_ask')
```

but does not work, I would not want to group by time window, that is why I would not want to do a groupby

could you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: @Kafels Could you help me?

Comment: Just a note, Stack Overflow does not notify a user even if you put @[user name] and I'm commenting here because it was a coincidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is that:

```
        df1 = self.tick_by_tick_data_processed\
            .select(
                f.col('localSymbol').alias('localSymbol_bids'),
                f.col('time').cast('string').alias('time_bids'),
                f.posexplode('domBids.price_bid').alias('id_bids','price_bids')
            )

        df2 = self.tick_by_tick_data_processed\
            .select(
                f.col('localSymbol').alias('localSymbol_asks'),
                f.col('time').cast('string').alias('time_asks'),
                f.posexplode('domAsks.price_ask').alias('id_asks','price_asks')
            )

        join_expr = "id_bids=id_asks AND localSymbol_bids=localSymbol_asks AND time_bids=time_asks"
        join_type = "inner"
        join_df = df1.join(df2, f.expr(join_expr), join_type)
```

and the result is:

```
+----------------+--------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+--------------------------+-------+----------+
|localSymbol_bids|time_bids                 |id_bids|price_bids|localSymbol_asks|time_asks                 |id_asks|price_asks|
+----------------+--------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+--------------------------+-------+----------+
|BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|0      |219.35    |BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|0      |213.45    |
|BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|1      |214.0     |BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|1      |213.46    |
|BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|4      |213.5     |BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|4      |213.5     |
|BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|2      |213.6     |BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|2      |213.5     |
|BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|3      |213.55    |BABA            |2021-06-10 13:23:50.701279|3      |213.5     |
+----------------+--------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+--------------------------+-------+----------+
```